# Given an input array, output the minimum number of swaps for sorting the array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Given an input array I want to calculate the minimum number of swaps to sort the array.
I thought that its equal to inversion count but its not as depicted below:

```
array [6,4,3]
```

output: 1, just swap 6 with 3. But the inversions are actually 3.

So given an input array is there an efficient algorithm to determine the minimum number of swaps. I know that selection sort has minimum number of swaps but I also know that it is not efficient.

Comment: @RohitRawat even though the top answer at that question answers a different question (the one that the OP meant but didn't ask), the second answer actually answers this question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this method:

Say this is your input array: `[4 6 1 8 2 7]`

Then, in sorted array, positions of elements will be, respectively: `3 4 1  6 2 5`

Create a visit array: `[0 0 0 0 0 0]`

Start with 1'st index in position array, mark it as visited, jump to the position it represents, until the value of visit in `visit[]` is set.

Then, once a cycle is complete, chose the next element whose `visit` value is unset.

For a cycle of `k` elements, add `k-1` to the swap counter.

Step by step in this example will be:

```
visiting index in position[]        visit[]

position[1] = 3                     [1 0 0 0 0 0]
position[3] = 1                     [1 0 1 0 0 0]
```

Now, a cycle is formed. Since this cycle has 2 elements, add 1 to swap counter. Now we start with index 2.

```
position[2] = 4                     [1 1 1 0 0 0]
position[4] = 6                     [1 1 1 1 0 0]
position[6] = 5                     [1 1 1 1 0 1]
position[5] = 2                     [1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Since `visit[2]` is set, a cycle is formed. This cycle has 4 elements, so, add 3 to swap counter.

See which next index in `visit` is still unset. (None). Stop here.

So, your answer is `1 + 3 = 4`